# '[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start' when running cloud-init?

Tags: docker, cloud-init, openstack

I am trying to contextualize a docker container using `cloud-init`.
Why do I see `[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start` in the OpenStack log?
What is a likely cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my rather limited experience, a likely reason is that the command `sudo docker image build` *does not find the docker file*.
(But a virtual machine may have been successfully created.)